# Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a sigma-algebra. Show that if $|\mathscr{A}| = ∞$ then $\mathscr{A}$ is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Asking for clarity of solution to $3(b)$:

> Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a sigma-algebra. Show that if $|\mathscr{A}| = ∞$ then $\mathscr{A}$ is uncountable. (Hint: You need to
>   show that there’s an infinite sequence of non-empty disjoint
>   measurable sets. How ? Take any non-empty set $A ∈ \mathscr{A}$. Then either $A$
>   or $A^c$ contains infinitely many measurable sets. Continue by
>   induction).

(See http://homepages.uconn.edu/benari/math5111s09/restricted/hw1_R1sol.pdf)

The solution goes:

> First we construct an infinite sequence of nonempty disjoint
>   measurable sets. Then we use that to show that $A$ contains
>   uncountably many sets.
>   **Let $A_1 ∈ \mathscr{A}$ which is neither $∅$ nor $X$. WLOG $A^{c}_1$ has an infinite number of measurable subsets** (make sure you
>   understand why. This follows from the assumption that A is infinite).
>   Continue by induction, assuming that $B_n = \{\bigcup_n^{j=1} A_j\}^c$
>   contains an infinite number of measurable subsets, we pick nonempty
>   $A_{n+1} ⊂ B_n$ in $\mathscr{A}$ such that $B_n-A_{n+1}$ has infinitely
>   many measurable subsets. By construction $A_1$, . . . are measurable
>   and disjoint. Now for each subset $I ⊂ N$, define $A_I = ∪_{n∈I}A_n$.
>   Clearly, $A_I ∈ \mathscr{A}$. Note that that the mapping $I → A_I$
>   from $P(N)$ to $\mathscr{A}$ is one-to-one. Since $P(N)$ is
>   uncountable, the claim follows.

I was wondering if this solution is legit. The proof argues that $A^{c}_1$ has an infinite number of measurable subsets. However, there could be infinitely many sets that intersects with $A_1^c$ and $A_1$ but these sets are not contained in either $A_1^c$ or $A_1$. Someone has argued this in reddit (which I don't think it make sense):

https://www.reddit.com/r/cheatatmathhomework/comments/1mgj91/analysis_sequence_in_sigma_algebra/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As usual, define the restriction of the sigma algebra to $A$ with as ${\scr A}\cap A=\{X\cap A: X \in {\scr A}\}$.

---

If ${\scr A}\cap A$ and ${\scr A}\cap A^c$ are finite, then as
$$
{\scr A}=\{X \cup Y: X\in{\scr A}\cap A\;\land \;Y\in {\scr A}\cap A^c\}
$$
one gets that $|{\scr A}|=|{\scr A}\cap A|\cdot|{\scr A}\cap A^c|$ is also finite.

Comment: It is the restriction of the sigma algebra to $A$, added to answer.

Comment: No, of course not. If you restrict to one of the disjoint sets, then this restriction has exactly one set. -- Note that a sigma algebra is the almost polar opposite of a collection of disjoint sets.

Comment: You do a disjoint split. At least one of the restrictions is an infinite sigma algebra. Distribute now the naming so that the restriction to $A_{n+1}^c$ is infinite, so that the splitting process can be continued.